# Why can I make an alias beginning with `:` colon, but not `;` in zsh?

Tags: zsh, alias

I know I can probably get around this by defining a function, but I was curious why the semicolon gives me so many bugs?

Comment: `;` is the character that separates commands.

Comment: You can **define** and alias with a leading semicolon, but I didn't find a way to **use** it. You can define it by `alias ';ll'=ls -l`, and you can prove that the alias exists (`type \ll` would show it), but I am not aware that you can actually call it afterwards: If you type just `;ll`, the shell takes the `;` as statement separator, and if you type  `\;ll`, the shell sees that you want to escape something in your command and disables alias expansion. Perhaps there **is** a trick to force zsh into doing the alias expansion, but I don't know it. My advice would be not using aliases at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`;` is a special shell character used to separate commands; for example this:

```
% ls /; ls /etc
```

Is (mostly) the same as if you had typed:

```
% ls /
% ls /etc
```

A `:` on the other hand is merely a special shell builtin, and can be overridden.

There may be tricks to override this; you can't "just" override it with functions either, but I would strongly recommend against it as I suspect it will only bring you confusion and errors. There are plenty of other characters on the keyboard that can be used :-)

---

That said, you can use a global alias to override `;` to call a function:

```
% alias -g ';'='semicolon'

% semicolon() { print -r -- semicolon: $@ }
% ;hello
semicolon: hello
```

You'll have to modify that `semicolon` function though.

Note this will apply *everywhere* on the commandline, including in the middle of a command:

```
% ls ; ls 
ls: cannot access 'semicolon': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'ls': No such file or directory
```

You could modify the `semicolon()` function a bit to be smart about at least some scenarios, but I would **strongly** recommend against it.